# Selecting one plot among diagnostic plots in R

Tags: r

I am trying to isolate only one plot among a 4-panel display of diagnostic plots using a GEV model.

This is what I tried to isolate the last plot of the 4 plots (i.e. the bottom-right plot):

```
superfit <- fevd(x=Gcomb, type="GEV")
plot(superfit, which=c(2,2))
```

But this results in this error:

```
Error in box(...) : invalid 'which' argument
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Why could this be happening?

Thank you, and I look forward to your response!

Comment: Can you provide more details about your issue such as a reproducible dataset (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), librairies used and an image of the four plot you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot` method for class `fevd` has an argument `type` and the following is from its document:

> Default is “primary”, which makes a 2 by 2 panel of plots including the QQ plot of the data quantiles against the fitted model quantiles (type “qq”), a QQ plot (“qq2”) of quantiles from model-simulated data against the data, a density plot of the data along with the model fitted density (type “density”) and a return level plot (type “rl”).

The fourth panel is the return level plot and you can extract it by

```
plot(superfit, type = "rl")
```

Comment: thanks for this response! Indeed, this worked just fine. I found that document, but it does not show any way to label the title of these plots. My last question is it possible to modify the default titles? Thanks, again

Comment: @Rain1290 Of course! Just set the argument `main` in `plot`, i.e. `plot(superfit, type = "rl", main = "xxx")`.